# Prove $\int_0^\infty \exp (-x^2) dx=\int_0^\infty \exp \left(-x^2 \left( 1-\frac{4}{x^2-2}\right)^2 \right) dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

It appears by numerical evaluation that:

$$\int_0^\infty \exp \left(-x^2 \left( 1-\frac{4}{x^2-2}\right)^2 \right) dx=\int_0^\infty \exp (-x^2) dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

The plot of the difference between functions on the RHS and the LHS can be seen below:

[image]

It's easy to see that $x=2$ is the positive solution to $\left( 1-\frac{4}{x^2-2}\right)^2=1$.

> I don't know how to solve the first integral, but maybe we can prove the equality by some indirect means?

If any substitution is possible, I don't know what that is. I've tried several, but they just lead to more complicated expressions.

> Also, I would like to know if this integral has a closed form (at least in terms of known special functions):

$$\int_0^2 \left( \exp (-x^2)- \exp \left(-x^2 \left( 1-\frac{4}{x^2-2}\right)^2 \right)  \right)dx$$

---

**Edit**

What if we just prove by some substitution that:

$$\int_0^2 \left( e^{-x^2}- \exp \left(-x^2 \left( 1-\frac{4}{x^2-2}\right)^2 \right)  \right)dx= \\ =\int_2^\infty \left( \exp \left(-u^2 \left( 1-\frac{4}{u^2-2}\right)^2 \right)-e^{-u^2}  \right)du$$

Comment: $-x^2 \cdot \left( 1-\frac{4}{x^2-2}\right)^2$=$-x^2+8-\frac{32}{x^4}+...$ when series-expanded at infinity. Not certain if they're identical so much as asymptotically similar.

Comment: @Αδριανός, the integrals are equal, but the exponents are obviously not. I've tried the series approach, but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall [G. Boole's result](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html), for any integrable function $f$, we have

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f\left(x-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_k}{x-b_k}\right)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\: \mathrm{d}x, \quad a_k>0. \tag1
> $$

Then apply $(1)$ with $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$, $a_0=a_1=2$, $b_0=-\sqrt{2}=-b_1$.

Comment: Thank you. This is a very nice theorem, is the proof very complicated?

Comment: @YuriyS You are welcome. The proof is not complicated, it is a bit 'latex-long' to write down.